# How to integrate Swagger documentation with Jersey?

Tags: rest, jersey, swagger

I have jersey rest web-services for which I want to add swagger documentation.I'm not using Maven. I didn't find exactly how to use it since most of the tutorials describe about using swagger along with jersey using Maven dependencies.

I went through [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/swagger-scalatra) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/swagger-make-developers-love) and many other tutorials including swaggers own **PetStore** example but that didn't yield any result. Being very new to all this I don't intend to change to Maven any time soon.

So is there any way I can still use swagger for my APIs?

I want it to work along with [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors.) (Just in case if it important to know).And I'm using Tomcat's `web.xml` to add `filters` for **CORS** support.

Tried some coding too but ended up with messing whole APIs resulting into `Internal Server Errors` often. So can anyone help me with a simple jersey project sample with swagger? Or exact set of jars that i would have to add to `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` for things to make it work.

Comment: did my answer help you @hegdekar?

Comment: no results yet. Tried it. provided all compile dependencies as you mentioned. But finally no progress

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Dont know why but if I get swagger UI to work JSON parsing of post requests seems to fail in particular classes.

Comment: check your Model class then.